# "Spread" quantities from points to underlying raster map within a radius

Tags: qgis, raster, distance, mapping

I need to generate a raster map by "spreading" point values to the surrounding pixels, with spreading criteria based on the pixel Boolean value (T/F) and maximum distance.
For example, if I have a point with value 100 (representing kg of manure), I want to spread those 100 kg in the surrounding pixels within a maximum distance (radius) of 20 km. Ideally I would also like to flag pixels that should not be considered (do not receive manure) using the Boolean value. The spreading can be homogeneous (all pixel get the same value until I reach 100) or follow a distance gradient, it is not so relevant at this stage, but the sum of all pixels must correspond to the sum of all points values.

So far I have prepared the points layer, the underlying raster binary map and the distance map with max radius but I am struggling to find the GIS tools/workflow to accomplish the "spreading", I have checked the distance analysis tools with little success. I ideally work with QGIS but also ArcGis is fine. I am more concerned about the strategy to follow than the tool itself.

Comment: Not a full-fledged answer, but take a look at the GRASS `r.buffer` processing algorithm which lets you specify up to 250 concentric zones (but the same ones over the whole buffer) and at the QGIS native Vector geometry `Buffer` processing algorithm, where you can specify the buffer distance as data-driven, i.e. depending on the value of an attribute of the point. Neither of these fully fit your requirements out of the box, but I think could be part of a workflow to get you there.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. Although what I look for is a way to limit the buffer area to the data-driven total value, taking holes into account, not just the radius (distance). I guess I might need to reformulate my task.